# Loading a script in the <body> section

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript for a specific page that I do not wish to be loaded in my header section. Is it possible to load it in the  section of the HTML.

Currently I have all my js code inside the  but I want to remove it to a seperate js file that I can load.

I tried using this but it did not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Q1** : I have a javascript for a specific page that I do not wish to be loaded in my header section. Is it possible to load it in the section of the HTML.

-Yes you can load javascript any where you want, if writing inline code then make sure you add script tag around your code.

-also you can request files like in body

**Q2**: Currently I have all my js code inside the but I want to remove it to a seperate js file that I can load.

-- no problem in that, thats even better practice.

**Q3** Requesting external file

to request external files you write below written fashion

```
<script src="http://file_name.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not only possible ([**ref**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element)), it's frequently a good idea.

Putting your scripts as late in the page as possible, which frequently means just before the closing `</body>` tag, means the browser can parse and display your content before stopping to go download your JavaScript file(s) (if external) and fire up the JavaScript interpreter to run the script (inline or external).

Putting scripts "at the bottom" is a fairly [standard recommendation](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) for speeding up the apparent load time of your page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Try and see.

For debugging, hardcode the jquery full path.

It is sometime recommended to load it at the end of the of the body, to make the main content of the page load faster.

Comment: *"Try and see."* There's a **big** difference between what works on the browsers you happen to try it on, and whether something is *meant* to work, reliably, cross-browser, now and in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to load it in the section of the HTML.

Yes.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-BODY):

```
<!ELEMENT BODY O O (%block;|SCRIPT)+ +(INS|DEL) -- document body -->
```

SCRIPT is among the elements that may be a child of the BODY elements. Numerous other elements may also have SCRIPT children.

> `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>`

When I run `echo base_url()` I get my the hostname of my server. This would result in a URL such as *example.comjs/query-1.5.1.min.js*. You probably should drop that PHP snippet entirely and just use: `src="/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"` which would resolve to ***http://**example.com**/**s/query-1.5.1.min.js*.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo engineers recommendation for higher performance is to include your scripts at the end of your HTML, just before `</body>` tag. Therefore, it's even better.

To see where the problem is, you gotta first make sure that your js file is loading. User **Firebug** and go to **scripts** tab. Do you see your script? If not, then something is wrong with your path.

Answer (score 0):

it should work...

Did you try to view the generated source and see if the PHP code indeed generated the right path?

beside that, it is recommended to load jQuery from a CDN such as google's : 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js