# How to overwrite placeholder text of input box

Tags: jquery, html, css, inputbox

I can't seem to figure out what is over writing the placeholder in this specific input box on a colour picker, I have a placeholder as":

```
placeholder="Type a hex (Or keyword)"
```

It's defaulting as "#FFFFFF" has anybody any idea why? I've tried to change both the value and placeholder of the input box and still nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being injected by javascript.

Try `value="Type a hex (Or keyword)"`

I'm not sure if this will work, it depends on the JS script of the colorpicker.

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately doesn't make any difference

Comment: Go to jscolor.js and replace `this.valueElement = target; // value holder` by `this.valueElement = "Type a hex (Or keyword)"; // value holder`

Comment: This works at removing the hex value, however when i use the color picker now, the chosen hex code doesn't apply to the input box anymore?

Comment: Try the way alex suggested.
Add `<script>$('#nobg').val('Type a hex (Or keyword)');</script>` at the bottom of the page, above </body>

Comment: Ok, in jscolor.js, I replaced 

this.valueElement = target;

with this.valueElement = target $('#nobg').val('');

it's acting the same, removing the value but when colour chosen from picker, it doesn't apply to the input box. Any further suggestions?

Comment: ignore my comment about jscolor.js undo that and the script i commented. `<script>$('#nobg').val('Type a hex (Or keyword)');</script>` at the bottom of the page, above </body>

Answer (score 0):

Your placeholder is not been showed because there is a value defined!

Placeholders are placeholders. They are there only when inputs are empty (value=="")

Set your default value as `""` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

@Companjo is correct, it is in fact because the javascript for your colorpicker is overriding the value. jscolor is written to automatically change the input when it's loaded. If you want to make a change a specific element's placeholder back to its original value you can update the `init` function in jscolor.js as so:

```
init : function() {
  if(jscolor.binding) {
    jscolor.bind();
  }
  if(jscolor.preloading) {
    jscolor.preload();
  }
  document.getElementById('nobg').value = '';  // this is the only new line
},
```

Comment: Thanks, @Companjo's suggestion  works at removing the hex value, however when i use the color picker now, the chosen hex code doesn't apply to the input box anymore?

Comment: That's why I recommended using the bit of script above. Changing the assignment of `this.valueElement` in jscolor.js is not a good idea since it will write over the variable that the library is using.

Comment: I totally get what your saying, and thanks for trying to help. I'm using this

    <script>
    $('#nobg').val('');
    </script>

in the head and I'm still seeing no changes

Comment: Is it after this line in the head? `<script src="assets/scripts/jscolor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` - I would suspect that would make a difference. However you could also load it at the [bottom of the body in the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643017/loading-a-script-in-the-body-section).

Comment: I've just tried both, still showing the hex value upon load with the script in place. :/

Comment: It wouldn't be anything to do with the ID? I just created that ID to style the background - the pre loaded class was 'search-input hex color'

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with the id since I can manipulate it in my javascript console when I load the page.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it working with that little piece of javascript, thanks for trying to help, appreciate it :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with some javascript (that's not jQuery javascript since jscolor doesn't use jQuery) to update the particular element's value.